# Java how to load a Class from another jar to my jar and how to use it

Tags: java, class, jar

//UPDATE//

Now I can load a Jar, but how can I run methods from it?

Comment: You have to implement a custom classloader

Comment: and how can I do this ?? Can you pls give example code

Comment: I think searching for *java create custom classloader* is not that hard. Anyway: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142%2Fhtml%2Fid1100.html

Answer (score 1):

From the main JAR file where you need to plug `games.jar`:

- First get the URL for your `games.jar` file (use `File.toURI().toURL()`) and put it in an array (let's call the array `urlArray`).
- Next get a `URLClassLoader` instance to load `games.jar`:

  ```
  URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urlArray);
  ```
- Now you can instantiate any class from the `games.jar` with the `Class.forName` if you pass the new class loader you just created as third parameter:

  ```
  Class<? extends Main> mainClass = (Class<? extends Main>)
  Class.forName("Main", true, urlClassLoader);
  ```
- On `mainClass` you can now call your method: `mainClass.loaded();`

Comment: And how can I then run code from these Class?

Comment: Class.forName() returns a Class object.  Call newInstance() on this object to get an instance of your class upon you can call any of its methods.

Comment: Ok so can U helpme ? I have one Jar with the Loader and in the second jar I have a Method which i want to run from the first, what I have to do ?

Comment: I edited the answer.  Hope it is more clear.  Just follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this. First, you need to import the jar. This can be done at runtime using a slight [hack with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60764/369450):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
```

```
public void importJar(File file) {
    Method addURL = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
    addURL.setAccessible(True);
    addURL.invoke(URLClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[] {file.toURI().toURL()});
}
```

Now you can import a jar at runtime. If you simply have the path to the jar, you can easily convert it to a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

```
importJar(new File("path/to/jar"));
```

Second, you need to find the classes defined in your jar. There does not appear to be a built-in way to do this, so you'll have to manually examine the jar itself for classes.

```
import java.lang.Class;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
```

```
public List<Class<?>> findJarClasses(File file) {
    ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        String name = entry.getName();
        if (name.endsWith(".class")) {
            name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.'));
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);
            classes.add(cls);
        }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Finally, you can iterate over the classes to determine if any of them implement your desired interface.

```
File jarFile = new File("path/to/Games.jar");
importJar(jarFile);
List<Class<?>> classes = findJarClasses(jarFile);
for (Class<?> cls : classes) {
    if (cls.isInstance(YourInterface.class)) {
        // Instantiate class.
        YearInterface obj = (YourInterface)cls.newInstance();
        // Call `loaded()` method.
        obj.loaded();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can i run a method in this Class?

Comment: You can instantiate the class using either `cls.newInstance()` or `cls.getConstructor(ArgumentClasses...).newInstance(arguments)` if the constructor has arguments. See also my update.

Comment: I always get an Error [11:35:29 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling Arcade v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: arcade/interfaces/game

Comment: @sentostv I'm unfamiliar that error. Perhaps you could add all of your jars to the classpath, and omit the `importJar()` call.

Comment: Ok so can U helpme ? I have one Jar with the Loader and in the second jar I have a Method which i want to run from the first, what I have to do ?

Comment: @sentostv Update your question with where you are stuck. Include any classes and which jars they belong to that may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a classloader with the jar's file url.
2. Ask the classloader to load the game's main class by name
3. Create a new instance of the game's main class
4. Cast it to some 'Game' interface your plugin loader knows
5. Invoke the methods on the interface to start the game.

Comment: Can you give Examples please ?